# Creating sqlite table from csv files with different column names

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, pandas, operationalerror

I have a large amount `.csv` files that I would like to put in a sqlite database. Most of the files contain the same column names, but there are some files that have extra columns.

The code that I've tried is (altered to be generic):

```
import os    
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

os.chdir(dir)
for file in os.listdir(dir): 
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df.to_sql('X', conn, if_exists = 'append')
```

When it encounters a file with column that is not in table `X` I get the error:

`OperationalError: table X has no column named ColumnZ`

How can I alter my code to append the table with the new column and fill previous rows with `NaN`?

Answer (score 0):

If all DataFrames can fit into RAM, you can do this:

```
import glob

files = glob.glob(r'/path/to/csv_files/*.csv')

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in files], ignore_index=True)
df.to_sql('X', conn, if_exists = 'replace')
```

Demo:

```
In [22]: d1
Out[22]:
   a  b
0  0  1
1  2  3

In [23]: d2
Out[23]:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6

In [24]: d3
Out[24]:
    x   b
0  11  12
1  13  14

In [25]: pd.concat([d1,d2,d3], ignore_index=True)
Out[25]:
     a   b    c     x
0  0.0   1  NaN   NaN
1  2.0   3  NaN   NaN
2  1.0   2  3.0   NaN
3  4.0   5  6.0   NaN
4  NaN  12  NaN  11.0
5  NaN  14  NaN  13.0
```

---

Alternatively you can store all columns as a list and check in a loop whether a new DF has additional columns and add those columns to the SQLite DB, using [SQLite `ALTER TABLE` statement](https://sqlite.org/syntax/alter-table-stmt.html):

```
ALTER TABLE tab_name ADD COLUMN ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't fit all the files in RAM. I like your method though, is there a way to use a chunk method and dump the `df` to free up RAM after each `df.to_sql`? I've tried `del df` but that isn't freeing the RAM up.